# When "an opponent" has to do something in a multiplayer game, who does it?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-multiplayer

In a multiplayer game of Magic: The Gathering, if a card requires an opponent to make a choice — like [Fact or Fiction](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fact%20or%20Fiction), which states an opponent separates the piles into two piles — who gets to pick which opponent makes that choice, e.g. which opponent separates them? Because in a tournament where four people play against each other and two of the people are friends it just seems unfair that the player can choose anyone to do it.

Comment: Remember, even disregarding friendships, there may be in-game reasons for one opponent to give another the cards they want, due to temporary alliances or cards that threaten others' board positions more than your own.

Comment: I've always found the political aspect to be the best part of multiplayer magic. If it's just for the interaction, there's better interaction in cube where the format is carefully crafted for fun gameplay, not infinite win combos. If these friends are in kahoots, either it's fun or it's not, but they have plenty of ways to interact without Fact or Fiction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The player who controls the spell chooses the opponent.

There could be some political issues here, but no more so than if you had a friend in a 4-player game who refused to attack you because you were friends. He's still your opponent in the game, so he should be making the decisions that will give him the best chance of winning; not trying to help you.

From the [comprehensive rules](http://media.wizards.com/2015/docs/MagicCompRules_20150123.pdf):

> 601.3. Some spells specify that one of their controller’s opponents does something the controller would
>   normally do while it’s being cast, such as choose a mode or choose targets. In these cases, the
>   opponent does so when the spell’s controller normally would do so.
>
> > 601.3a **If there is more than one opponent who could make such a choice, the spell’s controller
> >     decides which of those opponents will make the choice.**

Comment: The rules have changed, this is now 601.5a